# Lagrangian complement of lagrangian subspace

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let $(V,\omega)$ be a vector space over $K$ together with symplectic form $\omega : V \times V \rightarrow K$. Let $U \subseteq V$ be a Lagrangian subspace (in other words, $U = U^{\perp}$). I want to find another Lagrangian subspace $W$ such that $U \oplus W = V.$

So I have defined a partial ordering on the set $S$, which is defined to be the set of all isotropic subspace $M$ where $M\cap U=\{0\}$ ordered by $A \leq B$ if $A$ is a subspace of $B$. Now by Zorn's lemma, we can find a maximal element $W \in S$ and now we want to claim that $V=U\oplus W$ and if this were not the case, it should contradict the maximality of $W$ but I was not able to show that. How can we proceed or did I choose a bad partial ordering for Zorn's Lemma?

Comment: For finite spaces, if I'm not mistaken, a Gram–Schmidt like argument should do the job

Comment: also, that seems like a duplicate:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1350619/lagrangian-complement-in-symplectic-vector-space
but there isn't really an answer there?